# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion

*One of the [7 essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)*

How do we concisely define this site? Think along the lines:

- the tagline
- the motto
- the blurb under the logo
- a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
- perhaps eventually the domain name in some form

We are lucky with the name "Sports". It's short and suitable for nickname and domain. But we definitely need to work on the other points.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

"Are you familiar with Stack Exchange? It's a series of websites where people who know things or are good at finding out, can help answer questions about a number of special topics.
This is Sports.SE, which is the branch focused on competitive and professional sports' histories, rules, and trivia.
Not for deeply personal questions, or medical or fitness advice. But if it involves sports otherwise, we probably have a place for it!"
The whole thing is about thirty seconds of elevator pitch for the uninitiated. Trim off the first lines and it becomes a synopsis of Sports.SE for the site. Trim off the second and it becomes an ideal pair of taglines.